# Palka: Why does an infinite sequence of elements of a discrete subset $E$ of an open set $U$ necessarily have a limit point in a bounded component?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

This question is regarding Palka's proof of the Residue Theorem in *An Introduction to Complex Function Theory*, pp. 323-324.

> (Residue Theorem) Suppose that a function $f$ is holomorphic modulo isolated singularities in an open set $U$, that $E\neq\varnothing$ is the singular set of $f$ in $U$ and that $\sigma$ is a cycle in $U\setminus E$ which is homologous to zero in $U$. Then $\int_\sigma f(z)dz = 2\pi i\sum_{z \in E}n(\sigma, z)\mathrm{Res}(z, f)$

Palka begins his proof by first showing that $n(\sigma, z) \neq 0$ can hold only for finitely many elements of $E$. Then he writes:
[image]

My question is that why does "*none of the points $z_k$ can lie in the unbounded component of $\mathbb{C}\setminus |\sigma|$*" imply that "*$\left<z_k\right>$ must then have an accumulation point in $\mathbb{C}$*"?

This sounds like some sort of a Pigeonhole principle argument, but I am not sure about the specifics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the sequence $\langle z_k\rangle$ is a bounded infinite sequence, by the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem it admits a convergent subsequence. Therefore, $\langle z_k\rangle$ has a point of accumulation in $\mathbb{C}$.